# Combine data from different URLs in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one ajax request which i use to extract data from API, and create a table from the extracted data. Now i need to do the same, but to extract the data from two different URLs and merge is to the same table (`retTable`).

Here is my current code (one ajax request):

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url : '/url/status',
        type: "GET",
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            theRows = extract_status_data(data)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}

function extract_status_data(jsonDataRaw){
    jsonResultSect = jsonDataRaw['result']
    retTable = ""
    for( key in jsonResultSect){
        statusParam = jsonResultSect[key]

        a = statusParam['a']
        b = statusParam['b']
        c = statusParam['c']
        d = statusParam['d']
        e = statusParam['e']

        retTable += "<tr><td>" + dropDownList(key) + "</td><td>" + key +  "</td><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + c + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + e + "</td></tr>"

}
    return retTable
}
```

How would be correct to combine the data from two different URLs? Please advise.

Comment: Is this sorted data or does the order not matter?  I would think you could just do something like `$('#mytable').append(extract_status_data(data));` for each ajax request.

Comment: @JosephMarikle The order does matter and has a meaning. The parameter names (a, b, c..) are just an example. In my code they has names with meaning,

Comment: `a`,`b`,`c`, etc. will remain in the original order.  The *row* order will change.  Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/kp5w9xLu/.  If you run it enough times, the row with `test-result-2` will occasionally be the first row.

Comment: @JosephMarikle, Thanks for your help. The parameters of each URL are different. Each one of them suppose to be on his own column. Header for example: `a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2` (a1 - a parameter from url1, a2 - a parameter from url2). The amount of the parameters and their names of each URL is different.

Comment: Do they share the same key?  In my example I used "test-result-1" and "test-result-2".  Will the row data for "test-result-1" from the first ajax call also have the key "test-result-1" in the second ajax call?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes, they share the same key, and the data from both URL's suppose to combine 1 row together .

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but are there also multiple rows?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks for your help. You can ask how many questions you need. Yes, there are multiple rows. The json has multiple keys and i extract them in a loop for each key - `for( key in jsonResultSect)`. The key is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't hammer out a really robust solution right now, but here is what I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/heejse8h/

Basically the principal is that you place all the URLs in an array and keep a flag variable incrementing for every url you pull from.  This might look like this:

```
urls = [
  '/url/status',
  '/url/status2'
];

var i = 0;
```

Then when you execute the AJAX, you'll want to store that in some array

```
var result = [];
```

For my AJAX call in the jsfiddle, I used this basic structure

```
$.ajax({
  url : urls[i],
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
    // simplified example of storing the results
    // the example code from the fiddle is more
    // involved.
    result[key].push(data);

    if(urls[++i] !== undefined){
      // if there is another URL, use the same
      // ajax object (using `this`), extend it,
      // changing only the URL, and call it.
      // the important part is that the `this`
      // object has a reference to the currently
      // executing `success` method.
      $.ajax($.extend(this, {url: urls[i]}));
    } else {
      // otherwise, we're at the end of our URLs
      // and we can focus on final formatting and
      // display of the data.
      for( key in result ){
        $('#mytable').append("<tr><td>" + dropDownList(key) + "</td><td>" + key +  "</td>" + result[key].join('') + "</tr>");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In the end I would have liked to flesh this out and use the DOM API to actually create nodes rather than constant concatenation, but this solution already diverges from the original code quite a bit.  You might want to consider creating a function that parses an object rather than relies on concatenation.